# Making the Truecrypt bootloader less obvious on a dual Windows 7 system

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt

I have a system with two Windows 7 installations, one is encrypted with Truecrypt and the other is unencrypted. If I press Esc during pre-boot authentication, it will take me to the Truecrypt Boot Manager. Is there a way to set the truecrypt bootloader to default boot the unencrypted Windows 7 installation without showing "Truecrypt Boot Manager" in big bold letters?

Basically, I'm trying to make it less obvious that Truecrypt is installed on this system, so that if someone presses Esc without entering a password, it will directly boot the unencrypted Windows 7 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Make it read out the error about missing boot device or use a completely blank screen.

[image]

[image]

Simply leave the text field blank and people will think the computer is just broken. TrueCrypt will not show asterisks or anything at all while you type your password.

If you use hidden OS you should have the first OS run with a very simple password such as a single letter. That way you can set TrueCrypt as the default loader and enter the simple password without anyone noticing to boot the non-hidden OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by writing some random data into first sector using hex editor (I used [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)).

I've modified first 3 bytes to `00 00 00`. The next, block starting from `TrueCrypt Boot Loader` and ending with `00 00 00 (...)` I've overwritten with some random numbers and characters.

This made the drive completely unbootable and I can now boot from the usb or rescue cd to unlock and start system.